# Room Invalidation tracker is initialized twice (Room 2.2.0)

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I want to close and reopen my database in order to make an import/export to google drive. But I get this error.

I just do :

```
database.close() // database is injected through Dagger
// restoreDb
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(AppDatabase.NAME).path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)
```

If I observe data with Rx and a table is updated, I get this errors:

```
Invalidation tracker is initialized twice :/.
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: room_table_modification_log
E/ROOM: Cannot run invalidation tracker. Is the db closed?
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: room_table_modification_log (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM room_table_modification_log WHERE invalidated = 1;
```

I use room **2.2.0** and not 1.1.0

Thank you in advance for you help

Comment: Its happens when you made the modification in the table and didn't unistall after the modification and then run

Comment: Did you find any solution for that?